# iphone: NSURLCache on disk

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm having trouble with caching URLResponses to disk. I want that because the data i'm downloading needs reloading when the expires-tag in it's http-header is met, not earlier. Also, I want iPod touch-Users to be able to download the data once while online and then use it offline.

i'm doing this which works fine for caching things in memory but fails when relaunching the app:

```
NSURLRequest* menuRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:mensaURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval: 10];
NSCachedURLResponse* cachedMenuResponse = [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] cachedResponseForRequest:menuRequest];
if (cachedMenuResponse) {
    // received data is a member of that class to which the asynchronous 
    // download writes and which is then being used in updateDataFromDownload
    // to retrieve my data structure from the download.
    self.receivedData = [NSMutableData dataWithData:[cachedMenuResponse data]];
    [self updateDataFromDownload];
    NSLog(@"using data from cache");
} else {
    NSLog(@"opening connection");
    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:menuRequest delegate:self];
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK NSURLRequest/NSURLConnection support caching to disk from iOS 5.

*UPDATE*: @Rob correctly states in the comments:

> I've found that if (a) you use the default NSURLRequest cachePolicy of
>   NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy; and (b) the response doesn't
>   include the Cache-Control header, it won't cache to disk. If you use a
>   cachePolicy of NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad, or if the response
>   from the server specifies a particular Cache-Control header (e.g.
>   public, max-age=1835400), it will cache to persistent storage.

Comment: the documentation says it does, or at least implies that when providing methods to set the disk capacity used by the cache.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I still think it's not supported. See https://devforums.apple.com/message/182443#182443 and http://github.com/rs/SDURLCache, for example.

Comment: Thanks for that. SDURLCache offers an easy way to do exactly what i want :)

Comment: Apparently this now works, since iOS5 the disk is used. Check out "Cache.db" in the app caches directory... nicely saved requests.

Comment: @steipete: Have you actually gotten it to work on iOS5/6? The "Cache.db" file is created, but after restarting the app, it doesn't seem to read the requested data form the cache. It always fetches the data from the internet after a restart the first time, after that cached data is used, but I presume that it's using in-memory cache.

Comment: @YannickCompernol I've found that if (a) you use the default `NSURLRequest` `cachePolicy` of `NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy`; and (b) the response doesn't include the `Cache-Control` header, it won't cache to disk. If you use a `cachePolicy` of `NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad`, or if the response from the server specifies a particular `Cache-Control` header (e.g. `public, max-age=1835400`), it will cache to persistent storage.

Answer (score 3):

[SDURLCache](https://github.com/steipete/SDURLCache) is a great subclass of NSURLCache for on disk caching, very performance focused.

Hope this helps,
Vincent

Comment: It is a great library to use, though I hear that iOS 5.0+ has NSURLCache fixed to work on disk properly now. SDURLCache is good if you need more control.