# monotouch/objective c iphone 5.x how to cache web pages using NSURLCache?

Tags: objective-c, ios, caching, xamarin.ios, nsurlcache

i found similar thread to mine [iphone: NSURLCache on disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017152/iphone-nsurlcache-on-disk). What i want to do is basically almost the same : store web pages on my iphone simulator so that i can use them offline (load them to webview). When i am online i am downloading/caching them and when i go offline i use cached versions so that i can modify them while offline.

From what i've read since 5.0 iPhone allows caching on disk. My question is, how to do it using NSURLCache?

I went through some documentation of NSURLCache class but i couldn't find any specific answers nor examples.

Answer (score 0):

I recently implemented offline support in an app I was developing with Monotouch for iPhone. This is how I did it.

Firstly I got/created my application cache like so:

```
NSUrlCache _cache = NSUrlCache.SharedCache;
```

When I want to make a request for a URL I check whether I have a stored response in the application cache, else I send a request.

```
NSUrl url = new NSUrl ("http://whatever.com");
NSUrlRequest request = new NSUrlRequest (url);
NSUrlCachedResponse cacheResponse = _cache.CachedResponseForRequest (checkCacheRequest);

// check whether cache had response (would be null otherwise)
if (cacheResponse is NSCachedUrlResponse) {
    // cache has response load the cached page in the UIWebView
    _webView.loadData (cacheResponse.Data, "text/html", "UTF-8", url);
} else {
    //cache does not have response send a asynchronous request
    NSUrlConnection.FromRequest(request, myDelegate);
}
```

The delegate `myDelegate` is a subclass of NSUrlConnectionDelegate and should handle the response received from the request, however you want to implement that. I do not need to manually add the response to the cache as this is done automatically by `FromRequest`.

I have varied this method to allow my app to show a cached page, whilst checking for a newer version of the page with an If-Modified-Since header on my request. As far as I understand this is not permanent storage of the page as the system can clear the applications cache folder under certain situations. However, during my testing I have found the page to available offline after application close, and phone turn-on and turn-off, suiting my needs.

I hope this example helps.